# Boolean for unique value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

For my dataframe, e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 3, 7, 1], columns=['data'])
```

I want to know for each index if the value is unique in the column `data`.

So the resulting dataframe should be

```
    data    is_unique
0   1       False
1   3       True
2   7       True
3   1       False
```

Is there a convenient approach with pandas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with invert mask by `~`:

```
df['is_unique'] = ~df['data'].duplicated(keep=False)
print (df)

   data  is_unique
0     1      False
1     3       True
2     7       True
3     1      False
```

Answer (score 1):

One can use [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`pandas.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) as follows

```
df['is_unique'] = df['data'].map(df['data'].value_counts() == 1)

[Out]:

   data  is_unique
0     1      False
1     3       True
2     7       True
3     1      False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(df.client.to_list())

df["new_col"] = df.client.apply(lambda x:not(c[x] >1) )
```